# How can I get the n-th double precision number

Tags: floating-point, double

As I'm sure all of you know, floating point numbers are not represented as floats in binary. In fact they are stored in binary in a system where each 32 or 64 bits of numbers corresponds to a certain floating point number. Specifically with reference to double-word precision floating point numbers, can I, in any programming language, get the n-th double precision number. As in, is there a method/function in any programming language that would allow me to put in `253` and get the double that is stored as `11111101` in binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Java test program which I think does what you want. `Double.longBitsToDouble(in)` returns the double represented by the same bit pattern as `in`.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    testIt(0);
    testIt(253);
    testIt(-1);
  }

  public static void testIt(long in) {
    System.out.println(in + ": " + Double.longBitsToDouble(in));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
0: 0.0
253: 1.25E-321
-1: NaN
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.